# Lubuntu PowerPC with no apt repositories?

Tags: apt, macintosh, lubuntu

I've installed Lubuntu 13.04 on my G4 Mac Mini, however it didn't have any `apt` repositories, except from the CD. I've copied over the repositories from my i386 installation, but it can't find some of them. What repositories do I need to make it work?

**Output from `apt-get update`:**

```
...

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Old `/etc/apt/sources.list`:**

```
deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release powerpc (20130424)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe
```

**`/etc/apt/sources.list` copied from i386:**

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130423.1)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and write what exact version of Lubuntu, and the error messages that you have?

Comment: Also post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu since 7.04 doesn't provide updates to Power-PC architecture as said [here in the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads). So, how do you update? Simple, you download and upgrade using the Release CD's. Or if you want to get updates try this [method](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Which_repositories_have_PowerPC_packages.3F):

```
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130423.1)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring universe
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring universe
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring multiverse
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security universe
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security universe
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring-security multiverse


## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring main
deb-src http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring main
```

I tried to run `apt-get -s -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=sources.list.ubuntu update` to check out the list, but apt-get froze at 70% so, I'm not completely sure. You may have to use trial and error for this.

Ok, did some hammering with wget:

```
$ wget http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-powerpc/Packages.gz
--2013-09-03 11:19:54--  http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-powerpc/Packages.gz
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20 [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘Packages.gz’

100%[=====================================>] 20          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-09-03 11:19:54 (1.80 MB/s) - ‘Packages.gz’ saved [20/20]
```

It works. Or at least, is supposed to.

Comment: Thank you so much! I copied your sources.list and it worked (strange warning saying `W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main powerpc Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca_ubuntu-ports_dists_raring_main_binary-powerpc_Packages)` and 
`W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems` though, any suggestions?).

Comment: @PurpleDog only delete the last two lines, they are repeated.